# trying to export as exe and getting an error with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

so I'm trying to export this .py as an exe using pyinstaller. I have found it in path with cmd :

```
C:\Users\me>path
PATH=C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe
```

however, when I use this command:

```
C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\Rickroll>pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

I get the message

```
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

please can you help me understand why?

Comment: You should add the directory not the file to the PATH, there is a way though to add a single exe: https://superuser.com/questions/513932/add-a-single-exe-in-given-directory-to-path-environmental-variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i've fixed the problem. I essentially had to totally reset my computer. it did the trick. So essentially, the whole thing was messed up because of something my brother did on it a while back. the pip files were there but unresponsive. it was due for a reset anyway.,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).